# Calling javascript functions in static, Django

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Im struggling to understand why I cant call a javascript function when my Bootstrap button is clicked in Django.

I have created the static folder in my directory "main/static/main/js/script.js"
I am able to load the static css file for boostrap without any issues, but for whatever reason the javascript function "testing()" cant be called. Web browser console logs as Uncaught ReferenceError: testing is not defined onclick.
Am i suppose to use AJAX instead, or is there simply something wrong with my settings or url path.

EDIT: I realised my css static isnt working as well, i add some simple css styling and the changes were not reflected, only worked when i did inline styling

my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR /'main/static']
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

my scripts.js

```
function testing() {
  alert("Button clicked!");
}
```

my index.html, that is using bootstrap:

```
{%load static%}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <title>MoviePicks</title>
    <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap)-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{%static 'main/assets/favicon.ico'%}" />
    <link href="{%static 'main/css/styles.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body id="page-top">
    <!-- Header-->
    <header class="bg-dark bg-gradient text-white">
      <div class="container px-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">
        <!--code to play lottie animation file-->
        <lottie-player
          src="https://lottie.host/de506df5-436d-4157-9721-8cc927339ca6/BtifhCSc5e.json"
          background="transparent"
          speed="1"
          style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
          loop
          autoplay
        ></lottie-player>
        <!--____________________________________-->
        <button
          id="mainbtn"
          onclick="testing()"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-danger"
          style="
            --bs-btn-padding-y: 0.3rem;
            --bs-btn-padding-x: 1.5rem;
            --bs-btn-font-size: 1.75rem;
          "
        >
          Go!
        </button>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JS-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    <script src="{%static 'main/js/scripts.js'%}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ignore some of the closing tags if there are missing, i shortened the html codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR /'main/static']
```

Please tell me you didn't forget to put a comma in there right ?

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR ,'main/static']
```

Comment: <link href="{%static 'main/css/styles.css'%}" rel="stylesheet" />

This line loads in the css, but the css file is empty. I dont get. How is it styling with an empty file?